# Maintain Array of Objects when using product method

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have several array of objects that I need to use product on to get all possible combinations.

When I do the following, it works fine-

```
combinations = a1.product(a2,a3)
#combinations.class = Array
#combinations[0].class = Object
```

But if I try to add an array later using the same method, it will turn it into an array of arrays of objects-

```
combinations = combinations.product(a4)
#combinations.class = Array
#combinations[0].class = Array
#combinations[0][0].class = object
```

What do I need to change to maintain and array of objects?

Comment: You probably want `concat` but you need to explain what product does

Comment: I want to do the same thing I did in my first method call, add another "column" to the arrays and generate every possible combination of all "columns". Concat doesn't work for this case because it ends up merging the arrays.

Comment: I see, didn't realise this is Array.product (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-product). Not sure on the answer.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear but you are probably looking for a [`Array#flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten) method.

Comment: `[1,2,[3,4],[5,6, [7,8]],7].flatten #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7]`
So flatten should work for you.

Comment: I cannot parse your last sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have

```
a = [:a1, :a2]
b = [:b1, :b1]
c = [:c1, :c2]

e = a.product(b,c)
  #=> [[:a1, :b1, :c1], [:a1, :b1, :c2], [:a1, :b1, :c1], [:a1, :b1, :c2],
  #    [:a2, :b1, :c1], [:a2, :b1, :c2], [:a2, :b1, :c1], [:a2, :b1, :c2]]
```

When you take the product of `e` with:

```
d = [:d1, :d2]
```

you get:

```
f = e.product(d)
  #=> [[[:a1, :b1, :c1], :d1], [[:a1, :b1, :c1], :d2], [[:a1, :b1, :c2], :d1],
  #    [[:a1, :b1, :c2], :d2], [[:a1, :b1, :c1], :d1], [[:a1, :b1, :c1], :d2],
  #    [[:a1, :b1, :c2], :d1], [[:a1, :b1, :c2], :d2], [[:a2, :b1, :c1], :d1],
  #    [[:a2, :b1, :c1], :d2], [[:a2, :b1, :c2], :d1], [[:a2, :b1, :c2], :d2],
  #    [[:a2, :b1, :c1], :d1], [[:a2, :b1, :c1], :d2], [[:a2, :b1, :c2], :d1],
  #    [[:a2, :b1, :c2], :d2]]
```

but what you want is:

```
a.product(b,c,d)
  #=> [[:a1, :b1, :c1, :d1], [:a1, :b1, :c1, :d2], [:a1, :b1, :c2, :d1],
  #    [:a1, :b1, :c2, :d2], [:a1, :b1, :c1, :d1], [:a1, :b1, :c1, :d2],
  #    [:a1, :b1, :c2, :d1], [:a1, :b1, :c2, :d2], [:a2, :b1, :c1, :d1], 
  #    [:a2, :b1, :c1, :d2], [:a2, :b1, :c2, :d1], [:a2, :b1, :c2, :d2],
  #    [:a2, :b1, :c1, :d1], [:a2, :b1, :c1, :d2], [:a2, :b1, :c2, :d1],
  #    [:a2, :b1, :c2, :d2]]
```

You can obtain the result you want by mapping each element of `g` of `f` to `g.flatten`, as @DavidUnric suggested::

```
e.product(d).map(&:flatten)
```

or you could do it like this:

```
e.product(d).map { |a,f| a + [f] }
```